# WebBrowser, flash and Vista

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-vista, webbrowser-control, .net-3.5

I'm developing a win app, I'm using a WebBrowser control because a html editor was needed and we found a good one for asp.net. The problem is that when I put a swf file it just shows a small white box, and this only happens in win Vista, in XP or 7 everything's alright.

When I try to open the page created with the html editor (in IE7 on vista) the yellow box in the top appears and I think is because of IE7 configuration.

Any light on this one?

Thanks in advance for the help.
Ariel.

Answer (score -1):

Do you run the files **locally**? Then this is normal.

Comment: But I think there's a solution. I know that is normal, but I'm loking for a solution.